# Having trouble when executing Java in Debian 10

Tags: java

everyone, I am encountering trouble when executing Java in Debian 10

```
package ddd;

class Clothes {
    String color;
    char size;
}

public class Field {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clothes sun = new Clothes();
        Clothes spring = new Clothes();

        sun.color = "red";
        sun.size = 'S';        
        spring.color = "green";
        spring.size = 'M';

        System.out.printf("sun (%s, %c)%n", sun.color, sun.size);
        System.out.printf("spring (%s, %c)%n", spring.color, spring.size);
    }
}
```

when I executing it, the system returned me an error:

```
error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: ddd.Clothes
```

Can somebody figure out what is going on?

Comment: Do you start your java application from command line? Which command do you use?

Comment: You can put Clothes class inside of Field, but the file needs to be Field.java

Comment: You need to run it as `java dd.Field`  rather than `java dd.Clothes`

Comment: Please use an IDE, not a text editor to write your code

Comment: @Danill Yes, I start my java app from command line by javac

Comment: @cricket_007 what does it mean of "put Clothes class inside of Field"?

Comment: @StephenC It dosen't work

Comment: `public class Field { class Clothes {} }` inside of Field.java file

Comment: If you need us to tell you the precise command to use to run the app, you need to show us the directory structure, and file names, and what is in each relevant file, and tell us the precise commands that you used to compile and *try to* run it.  Include any `cd` commands.  Put all of the information into the question.